# Installing ImageMagick / PECL error, missing 'magick-wand.h'

Tags: php, macos, imagick, pecl

I installed imagick with homebrew on OS X Yosemite and want to install the imagemagick PHP extension with PECL. I am using the standard Apache server and PHP version included with the OS (not MAMP!). So, I tried

```
pecl install imagick
```

During the make process I get the error message

```
In file included from /private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_file.c:21:
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/php_imagick.h:51:12: fatal error: 'wand/magick-wand.h' file not found
#  include <wand/magick-wand.h>
            ^
1 error generated.
```

When asked for the prefix of the Imagemagick installation

```
Please provide the prefix of Imagemagick installation [autodetect] :
```

I am not sure what to enter but I tried empty (autodetect), "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-8/include/ImageMagick-6", and "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-8"

There is a "magick-wand.h" file located in "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-8/include/ImageMagick-6"/wand/magick-wand.h"

How do you install the imagemagick extension on OS X?

Comment: Step 1 - install vagrant. Step 2 - install a centos guest. Step 3 install Imagick on the centos guest. Or you could try mac ports - https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=php5-imagick

Comment: I wouldn't try macports since it might interfere with my homebrew installation. Isn't it a bit of an overkill to install a virtual machine just to get one extension to work? Is there no possibility to get the dependencies right? (no solution I found online did work so far, though) Or is everyone on OS X using virtual machines for web development (if they aren't using MAMP)?

Comment: Every sane person uses the same environment to develop in as they deploy software in...and I don't see many OSX servers. If you really wanted to you could probably have more luck installing Imagick from source yourself rather than through PECL - at least that would be easier to set the relevant flags/paths.

Comment: You have a point there.. I guess I should give your recommendation a try! Oh, and I tried building it from source as well - with the same outcome. Setting the flags led to some "lazy symbol binding failed" error.

Answer (score -3):

I got the same problem in OSX 10.10.3 with standard Apache, PHP in OSX

I found a solution from a blog.

http://charles.lescampeurs.org/2013/06/18/add-c-header-include-path-pecl

As the result, you only can compile the extension manually (I tried 3.1.2)

If you don't want to manually compile the source code, you may install the beta version of imagick (I try 3.3.1RC)

Comment: Hi WengKit Lei! Thank you for your answer, but I already followed Danack's advice and set up an environment using vagrant for the moment and it works fine!